# Finding largest minimum distance among k objects in n possible distinct positions?

Tags: algorithm

What is an efficient way to find largest minimum distance among k objects in n possible distinct positions?

For eg:

N: Number of distinct positions
Lets say N = 5
and the 5 positions are {1,2,4,8,9}

K: Number of objects let say k = 3

So the possible answer (Largest Minimum Distance) would be: 3 if we put objects at {1,4,8} or {1,4,9}

Comment: What is "largest minimum"

Comment: "Largest Minimum" is the distance between the objects finally placed at some k position available, which in above case is 3. For eg. Distance between 1 and 4 is 3, 4 and 8 is 4.

Comment: You asked the problem when it was live on codechef. Its not ethical. You should respect rules and regulations of codechef contests. :( http://www.codechef.com/CONI2015/problems/CN03

Comment: I didn't intended to submit the problem. :-) So no malicious intent. It was just for learning purpose as no tutorials would have been available :-( @NewUser

Comment: But you should have waited few hours till the end of contest. You can always ask about contest problems after the contest ends.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Let's do a binary search over the answer.
2. For a fixed answer `x`, we can check whether it is feasible or not using a simple linear greedy algorithm(pick the first element and then iterate over the rest of the array adding the current element if the distance between it and the last picked element is greater than or equal to `x`). In the end, we just need to check that the number of picked elements is at least `k`.

The time complexity is `O(n * log MAX_A)`, where `MAX_A` is the maximum element of the array.

Here is a pseudo code for this algorithm:

```
def isFeasible(positions, dist, k):
    taken = 1
    last = positions[0]
    for i = 1 ... positions.size() - 1:
        if positions[i] - last >= dist:
            taken++
            last = positions[i]
    return taken >= k

def solve(positions, k):
    low = 0 // definitely small enough
    high = maxElement(positions) - minElement(positions) + 1 // definitely too big
    while high - low > 1:
        mid = (low + high) / 2
        if isFeasible(positions, mid, k):
            low = mid
        else:
            high = mid
    return low
```

Comment: I am not getting how to use binary search here?

Comment: @JitendraSarswat If we fix the desired answer, we can check if it feasible or not(and it is monotonic). Thus, we can use binary search to find the largest feasible answer.